# My custom cell will not budge, everything I add gets stuck to the left wall

Tags: swift, xcode, uistoryboard

I am working with xcode and I can't seem to get my custom cell to budge. I have the constraints set up and even reset them a couple of times but they continue to look a lot different when I run my simulator.

Here is a screenshot of my constraints:

[image]

Here is an screen shot of my simulator:

[image: Simulator Preview]

I have tried deleting the labels and imageView and then adding it again and reset the constraints a few times. Anyone else getting these problems?

Comment: First thing to check, are there any messages in the debug console about "Unsatifiable Constraints"? My first guess is that you are defining too many constraints and it cant satisfy them all some some are being broken.

Comment: @CraigSiemens there is a good amount of them. Do you think I should just clear all constraints and start again?

Comment: @CraigSiemens problem solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining too many constraints. It is key for you to always use THE LEAST number of constraints as possible. 
From what I can see you are giving the labels  '5' and 'Orders need to be viewed' constraints to the leading edge of the cell. If you are also setting a second leading constraint to the image (hard to tell from the image, code would be easier to debug) this contradiction would break your constraints.

What you want is to have the image leading edge to the cell and give it a height and width and a top constraint only.

Give the '5' label  'horizontal spacing' ( ctrl drag ) to both the image and the second label. 
Provide a height and width for it and a top constraint.

- IMPORTANT
  since you have defined a horizontal spacing from the '5' to the other label, you do not need to provide another leading constraint to the last label. 
  simply give it a height, width, top constraint and trailing edge to cell

That should be all you need !

If this is too confusing let me know and I can share some snippets for more visualization

Comment: Thanks a lot Julian. Some how this paragraph has allowed me to better understand the purpose of constraints and their application.